# Not Execute specific T-SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

Goal:
If the file do not exist the code for openrowset and @XML.nodes shall not be executed.

Problem:
What and how should the syntax code be if the file do not exist by using T-SQL code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First -> google for 'SQLCLR File Functions'

or this way:

```
DECLARE @isExists INT 
exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'yourfilename', @isExists OUTPUT
SELECT case @isExists when 1 then ‘Yes’ else ‘No’ end as isExists
```

Furthermore, you will find interesting what the manual tells you about:

(google) 'TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)'

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql server built-in extended procedure `master.dbo.xp_fileexist`:

```
declare @result int
exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\aaaa.xml', @result output

if @result <> 0
begin
    set @xml = ...
emd
```